# Trouble modifying ngResource result

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I had the following in my code:

```
function store() {

    this.products = [
        new product("sku001", "Apple", "Tasty stuff", 1.00, "local"),
        ...
    ];
```

This worked fine for displaying all the products:

```
<h3>Products</h3>
<b>Display products: {{store.products}}</b>
<div class="row"> 
    <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <img ng-src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/products/{{product.sku}}.png")" alt="{{product.name}}"><p></p>
    <p>{{product.description}}</p>
</div>
```

Products displayed:

[image: display_products]

Now instead of hardcoding the values, I want to load them from a restful api:

```
function store($resource) {

    var Resource = $resource('/api/products/');

    this.products = Resource.query();

    console.log(this.products)
```

This also appears to work okay, but the formatting of the values is slightly different (Upper-case / differing key names):

```
 [{"SKU":"sku001","Name":"Apple","ProductType":"local","Description":"Tasty stuff","Allowance":1073741824,"Price":1}]
```

I wanted to use the data I received from the API to create an array of objects which matches my current formatting but I am having some issues:

```
function store($resource) {
    var Resource = $resource('/api/products/');

    this.products = Resource.query(function (data) {

        var product = {};
        var productsList = []
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            product = {
                sku: data[i].SKU,
                name: data[i].Name,
                description: data[i].Description,
                price: data[i].Price,
                category: data[i].ProductType
            }
            productsList.push(product);
        }
        return productsList;

    });
```

When I run the code, this gets outputted:

[image: updated image]

As you can see, the json displayed has not been modified and as a result, the description / price are not displayed.

Does anybody know how I can modify data loaded using $resource and then display it?

**Edit**

controller.js

```
function storeController($scope, $routeParams, DataService) {
    // get store and cart from service
    $scope.store = DataService.store;
    $scope.cart = DataService.cart;
}
```

app.js

```
var storeApp = angular.module('AngularStore', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).
//route stuff
}]);

storeApp.factory("DataService", function ($resource) {

    var myStore = new store($resource);
    var myCart = new shoppingCart("AngularStore");

    // return data object with store and cart
    return {
        store: myStore,
        cart: myCart
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function store($resource) {
    var Resource = $resource('/api/products/');

    Resource.query(function (data) {

        var product = {};
        var productsList = []
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            product = {
                sku: data[i].SKU,
                name: data[i].Name,
                description: data[i].Description,
                price: data[i].Price,
                category: data[i].ProductType
            }
            productsList.push(product);
        }
        $scope.products =  productsList;

    });
}
```

When you use `this.products = Resource.query(function (data) {...}`, `this.products` receives the return value of `Resource.query()`, not the return value of the callback function.

Edit

Use `$scope`, not `this`.

Comment: Hey, I gave this a try but it seems that the `this.products` variable never gets any value. The result looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/GV4ztv2.png)

Comment: `this` inside the callback means another thing then, that's why I avoid using `this`. Use $scope.products instead.

Answer (score 1):

As of Angular 1.2, resources support promises. But they didn't change the rest of the behavior.

To leverage promises with $resource, you need to use the $promise property on the returned value.

```
function store($resource) {
    var Resource = $resource('/api/products/');

    Resource.query().$promise.then(
    //success callback
    function (data) {

        var product = {};
        var productsList = []
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            product = {
                sku: data[i].SKU,
                name: data[i].Name,
                description: data[i].Description,
                price: data[i].Price,
                category: data[i].ProductType
            }
            productsList.push(product);
        }
        this.products = productsList;

    },
    //error call back
    function(){
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Howdy - I gave this a go and I'm getting a weird result you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/TgDO6M3.png). The variable is displayed as `{}` and `ngRepeat` seems to think there are 3 items.. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: have you debugged it?

Comment: @Tomcelic can you put console.log(data); inside success callback?

Comment: I put `console.log(data)` at the start of the callback and got this: `[{"SKU":"sku001","Name":"Apple","ProductType":"local","Description":"Tasty stuff","Allowance":1073741824,"Price":1}]`.

I also put `console.log(productsList);` at the end and got:

`[{"sku":"sku001","name":"Apple","description":"Tasty stuff","price":1,"category":"local"}]`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tomcelic Why you are not using $scope inside your controller?

Comment: Try this code 
function store($resource,$scope) {
    var Resource = $resource('/api/products/');
    $scope.products = Resource.query();
    console.log($scope.products)
}

Comment: `products` is a part of an object called `store`. In my controller, I have `$scope.store = DataService.store;` So in my html I should be able to access `store.products`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68275/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-tom-celic).

Comment: service should not be called directly from UI..it should use controller scope.

Comment: add this $scope.$watch(function () { return store.product }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (angular.isDefined(newVal)) {
        if(!$scope.$$phase)
   $scope.$apply();
    }
}); inside your controller...hope this will resolve the issue..you need to add service dependency on controller